# Voice chat for Unity 2017.2

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io, real-time-multiplayer

I have a multiplayer game code for 2017.2 version of Unity. I need to make it work with Agora.  But when I try to download, it does not work because the SDK is made available only for latest (Unity 2018.2) Unity version.

But due to the mess with High Level API of Unity, I need to stick to 2017 itself. Also my code base is on 2017.2.  Where do I find the Agora voice SDK for Unity, compatible with Unity 2017.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Demo your are trying may need you to have the latest Unity version, but Agora SDK does not.

You can use Agora SDK directly with Unity 2017.2.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the Unity SDK directly from Agora's developer portal
https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Gaming/downloads